# KDE Kontact applications fail to start. The Akonadi personal information management service is not operational

Tags: kde5, kde-neon

In looking for a good suite of mail/contacts/calendar .etc apps, I tried out KDE's [Kontact](https://userbase.kde.org/Kontact) and ran into the following issue upon starting pretty much any of the bundled applications (kmail, korganiser .etc). The application would display a loading screen like Image 1, and then it would display the error in Image 2, saying `The Akonadi personal information management service is not operational.` or something to that effect.

Image 1:
[image: loading...]

Image 2:
[image: Error]

Here is my system info as provided by `screenfetch`:

```
 OS: KDE neon 5.12
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.13.0-45-generic
 Uptime: 4h 37m
 Packages: 2060
 Shell: bash 4.3.48
 Resolution: 1280x800
 DE: KDE 5.47.0 / Plasma 5.13.1
 WM: KWin
 GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: breeze
 Font: Noto Sans Regular
 CPU: Intel Core2 Duo P8700 @ 2x 2.534GHz [36.0°C]
 GPU: intel
 RAM: 1802MiB / 2946MiB
```

I have already tried uninstalling (and reinstalling) the Kontact suite (both with and without the `--purge` argument to `apt` and <del>for some reason the "Details" button provided on the error screen appears to do nothing when i click on it.</del>

I had already saved the [selftest report](https://pastebin.com/P54Aeh3q) file to my desktop and then subsequently forgot it was there (redactions mine).

Comment: Posting this as a comment since I do not have enough reputation points to post it as a separate answer. I encountered similar error while starting the knotes application in Debian 10 (Buster). I was able to solve it by installing the akonadi-backend-mysql package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

The error logs show that the akonadi verion of the `mysql` server that these K* applications require is trying to access `~/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/`  except `db_data` doesn't exist, so it throws an error much like `touch ~/nonexistent_dir/file.txt` would.

To solve, simply run the below commands.
`cd ~/.local/share/akonadi/; mkdir db_data`

---

## Explaination

After doing a lot of digging around on the internet (there was a decent amount of information but most of it was incomplete/unsolved forum threads about similar but not identical issues with Akonadi) I was able to find [this](https://userbase.kde.org/Akonadi#ApplicationTable) general summary of Akonadi from KDE which was an excellent kickstart into my own investigating.

After playing around with the commands mentioned in the link, I got the following output (redactions mine):

```
$ akonadictl start
$ Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
mysqld: [ERROR] Could not open required defaults file: /home/[my username]/.config/akonadi/
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: database server stopped unexpectedly
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/[my username]/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/[my username]/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/tmp/akonadi-[my username].UXCgLp/mysql.socket", "--pid-file=/tmp/akonadi-[my username].UXCgLp/mysql.pid")
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stdout: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: "mysqld: Can't change dir to '/home/[my username]/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)\n2018-06-21T19:34:18.989616Z 0 [Warning] The syntax '--log_warnings/-W' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--log_error_verbosity' instead.\n2018-06-21T19:34:18.989703Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).\n2018-06-21T19:34:18.991172Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/[my username]/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/[my hostname].lower-test\n2018-06-21T19:34:18.992274Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 11859 ...\n2018-06-21T19:34:19.006500Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/[my username]/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/[my hostname].lower-test\n2018-06-21T19:34:19.006549Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/[my username]/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/[my hostname].lower-test\n2018-06-21T19:34:19.006623Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to /home/[my username]/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/\n2018-06-21T19:34:19.006632Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting\n\n2018-06-21T19:34:19.006658Z 0 [Note] Binlog end\n2018-06-21T19:34:19.006726Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete\n\n"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: exit code: 1
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: process error: "Unknown error"
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/akonadi-[my username].UXCgLp/mysql.socket' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/akonadi-[my username].UXCgLp/mysql.socket' exists!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Failed to remove runtime connection config file
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application 'akonadiserver' exited normally...
```

This produces a couple interesting lines. The problematic one being `org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: "mysqld: Can't change dir to '/home/[my username]/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)`. To me this looked like the program was trying to write to a directory to which it didn't have access and was throwing an error, much like `touch ~/nonexistent_dir/file.txt` would.

So I ran `cd ~/.local/share/akonadi/; mkdir db_data` and retried it. Bam it worked.

Comment: Note: if this doesn't work for you, try uninstalling the `akonadi-server` package from the command line and deleting `~/.config/akonadi/` and `~/.local/share/akonadi/` before reinstalling `akonadi-server` and its dependent packages (`akonadi-server kdepim-runtime kmail knotes kontact korganizer`).

Comment: also, it turns out that i had already saved the error log from the "details button in the error message" to my desktop, so here it is: https://pastebin.com/P54Aeh3q. it shows the same error that i fixed under the "test 15" section of the file

Comment: I resolved this by ditching the MySQL backend and going with PostgreSQL instead, besides being a more stable and higher performance DBMS, I already have it installed and use it for other things anyway.  I cannot remember the last time I used MySQL and I don't understand why it is still used for new projects.

Answer (score 3):

Similar problem, different solution. Mine was diagnosed as such:

```
$ akonadictl --verbose start                                      
....
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Executing: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi" "--defaults-file=/home/dargaud/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf --datadir=/home/dargaud/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/ --socket=/run/user/10705/akonadi/mysql.socket --pid-file=/run/user/10705/akonadi/mysql.pid"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: database server stopped unexpectedly

$ tail /var/log/syslog                      
audit: type=1400 audit(1593423663.888:404): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/dargaud/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test" pid=156675 comm="mysqld-akonadi" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=10705 ouid=10705
```

Solution, *adding* the following two lines to the apparmor config file for mysqld:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
/{,var/}run/user/[0-9]*/akonadi/** rw,
/home/*/.local/share/akonadi/** rwk,
```

Followed by:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apparmor.service
$ akonadictl --verbose start
```